# Showing system of trig equations has no solution

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

I'm working on a larger proof, but need to show that the following has no solutions. $$0 \le x,y < 2\pi$$
$$
R\cos(x)-C\cos(x) = R\cos(y)+C\cos(y)\\
R\sin(x)-C\sin(x) = R\sin(y)+C\sin(y)
$$
I've tried for a few hours, but have not found a concise method to show this is true.

I know already that the following can yield a solution, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.
$$
C(-\cos(\frac{x}{2} + \frac{x}{2}) - \cos(\frac{y}{2} + \frac{y}{2}) = R(\cos(\frac{y}{2} + \frac{y}{2}) - \cos(\frac{x}{2} + \frac{x}{2}))\\
        C(-\sin(\frac{x}{2} + \frac{x}{2}) - \sin(\frac{y}{2} + \frac{y}{2}) = R(\sin(\frac{y}{2} + \frac{y}{2}) - \sin(\frac{x}{2} + \frac{x}{2}))
$$
Simplifes to
$$
-2C\cos(\frac{x}{2} - \frac{y}{2}) \cos(\frac{x}{2} + \frac{y}{2}) = 2R\sin(\frac{x}{2} - \frac{y}{2}) \sin(\frac{x}{2} + \frac{y}{2})\\
        2C\sin(\frac{x}{2} + \frac{y}{2}) \cos(\frac{x}{2} - \frac{y}{2}) = 2R\sin(\frac{x}{2} - \frac{y}{2}) \cos(\frac{x}{2} + \frac{y}{2})
$$

Comment: Caveat: $R,C\ne0$

Comment: So, you have $$(R-C)\cos x=(R+C)\cos y \quad\text{and}\quad (R-C)\sin x=(R-C)\sin y$$ Square both equations, and add to get $$(R-C)^2 (\cos^2x+\sin^2x) = (R+C)^2(\cos^2y+\sin^2y) \quad\to\quad (R-C)^2=(R+C)^2\quad\to\quad\cdots$$

Comment: Oh that's much nicer. After simplifying I reached $$-RC = RC$$. Thank you.